# Does React Data Grid have "Read Only Deletion" in addition to "Read Only Edit"?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

React Data Grid has a [Read Only Edit](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/value-setters/#read-only-edit) feature that allows you to turn the grid into something like a ["controlled"](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) component:

> Use this if you want to manage the grid data state externally, such as in a Redux store.

It works well for edits, but I can't find a way to handle cell value deletions in a similar way. When you press `Del` while focusing on a table cell, the deletion seems to happen in-place. There doesn't seem to be a "cellDeletionRequest" which complements the existing ["cellEditRequest"](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/cell-editing/#editing-events).

Consider [this example](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/value-setters/#example-read-only-row-data) from the docs. Before completing an edit:

[image]

After completing it:

[image]

However, deleting a cell doesn't seem to trigger any deletion request, the cell's value is updated in-place, making it difficult to externalize the grid's state:

[image]

Is there a workaround for this apparent limitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, ag-grid doesn't seem to have a function like `cellDeleteRequest`
or detecting cell deletions yet. But you could use `onCellValueChange` to detect general events of a changing cell value including cell deletion.

Have read of [Column Events](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-properties/#reference-events) for more detail about `onCellValueChange`

Hope this would be helpful!